# Programmatically creating a node

Tags: 7, nodes

I am trying to create content from a cron job with a custom node type that contains just a title and body; the content type is mycontent (for argument sake).

I am trying to use the Entity API module because apparently it is supposed to be simpler.

Working from examples, I wrote the following code.

```
$values = array(
    'type' => 'mycontent',
    'uid' => $user->uid
  );
$entity = entity_create('node', $values);
$ewrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('node', $entity);
$ewrapper->title->set('My Title');
```

Clearly I am missing something here because I get an exception (*EntityMetadataWrapperException: Unknown data property title*).

So I changed it to the following.

```
$values = array(
    'type' => 'mycontent',
    'uid' => $user->uid
  );
$entity = entity_create('mycontent', $values);
$ewrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('mycontent', $entity);
$ewrapper->title->set('My Title');
```

Now I get a different error, an obtuse *Invalid data value given*.

Why cannot I get the Entity API module to work as advertised?

The current user in this case is user 1, not the anonymous user. If I add the content using Drupal standard functions, it works. So I know I am not having a permission issue.

I looked at [this example](https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/howtos/create-a-node-in-code), to write my code, and then proceeded to google a lot.

Comment: Can't you just put the title in the $values array?

Comment: Yes but if I do it does not save correctly. No node is created. I am not doing something right but have no idea what is wrong. I have added a link to the example page I was using.

Comment: In the second example you're trying to create an entity from a type that isn't defined (mycontent). Need to have a valid entity here, like node, user, commerce_order, etc.

Comment: Also, unless you have special code, cron runs as anonymous user... but this code should definitely work, unless your node type does not have a title. You aren't using something like Title Field module or anything like that? Is "title" definitely a property of the node type or is it a field?

Comment: These examples here are different than the one you posted: https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/api/entity-api/entity-metadata-wrappers

Comment: The anon issue was covered in my post. I have been to the link you provided and it gave no further clues as to the issue. I haven't implemented an entity class as I have no reason to. The example on that page is very similar to my code.   It would fail at the line `$emw_node->title = 'Test node';`

Comment: To rule my content type out as a possible cause of the error. I used the example at `drupal.org/docs/7/api/entity-api/entity-metadata-wrappers` with the basic page type `$node = entity_create('node', array('type' => 'page'));` It failed in exactly the same way.

Answer (score 7):

This will work for you:

```
$node = new stdClass();
$node->title = "My title";
$node->type = "mycontent";
node_object_prepare($node); 
$node->uid = $user->uid; 
$node->status = 1;
$node = node_submit($node);
node_save($node);
```

More details you can see at
https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/howtos/create-a-node-in-code